# Domain Model + LINQ to SQL sample

Tags: linq, unit-of-work, domain-model

I wonder if there is an enterprise application sample, designed with Domain Model in the Business Logic layer and LINQ for the Data Mapper? I'm not so sure of how to use the UnitOfWork ability of LINQ to SQL in conjunction with business objects from the Business Layer.

Thanks,
Lucian

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [MVC Storefront](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/mvc-storefront-part-1/). It uses Linq to Sql, domain driven design and ASP.NET MVC presented in webcasts and blog posts. Highly reccomended!

Answer (score 3):

I just published a simple sample using T4 templates, IoC with StructureMap etc. http://daniel.wertheim.se/2010/03/14/linq-to-sql-how-to-separate-the-entities-and-the-datacontext/

Check the comment. I'm about to make an update to the United of work implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend having a look at http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx